# Detect uniform images that (most probably) are not photographs

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

Take a look at these two example images: [image: Some background image] [image: Sticky tape]

I would like to be able to identify these types of images inside large set of photographs and similar images. By `photograph` I mean a photograph of people, a landscape, an animal etc.

I don't mind if some photographs are falsely identified as these `uniform images` but I wouldn't really want to "miss" some of these by identifying them as photographs.

The simplest thing that came to my mind was to analyze the images pixel by pixel to find highest and lowest R,G,B values (each channel separately). If the difference between lowest and highest value is large, then there are large color changes and such image is probably a photograph.

Other idea was to analyze the Hue value of each pixel in similar fashion. The problem is that in HSL model orangish-red and pinkish-red have roughly 350 degree difference when looking clockwise and 10 degree difference when looking counterclockwise. So I cant just compare each pixel's Hue component because I'll get some weird results.

Also, there is a problem of noise - one white or black pixel will ruin tests like that. So I would need to somehow exclude extreme values if there are only few pixels with such extremes. But at this point it gets more and more complicated and I'm feeling it's not the best approach.

I was also thinking about bumping contrast to the max and then running test like the RGB one I described above. It would probably make things easier but still one or two abnormal pixels would ruin the test anyway. How to deal with such cases?

I don't mind running few different algorithms that would cover different image types. But please note that I'm dealing with images from digital cameras so 6MP, 12MP or even 16MP are quite common. Because of that running computation intensive algorithms is not desired. I deal with hundreds or even thousands of images and have only limited CPU resources for image processing. Lets say a second or two per large image is max what I can accept.

I'm aware that for example a photograph of a blue sky might trigger a false positive, but that's OK. False positives are better than misses.

Comment: Have you looked into texture classification? You may find for your "uniform" images that one or more texture classifiers will yield a consistent measure across the image. If an > N% of an image consists of a given texture, then you can probably classify it as "uniform." That's too hand-wavy a suggestion, but maybe it'll help. Local Binary Patterns are a recent approach to texture classification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns

Answer (score 3):

This how I would do it (Whole Method below, at the bottom of post, but just read from top to bottom):

Your quote:

> "By photograph I mean a photograph of people, a landscape, an animal
>   etc."

My response to your quote:

> This means that such images have edges, contours. The images you are
>   trying to separate out, no edges or little contours(for the second
>   example image at least)

Your quote:

> one white or black pixel will ruin tests like that. So I would need to
>   somehow exclude extreme values if there are only few pixels with such
>   extremes

My response:

> Minimizing the noise through methods like DoG(Difference of Gaussian), etc will reduce the
>   noisy, individual pixels

So I have taken your images and run it through the following codes:

```
cv::cvtColor(image, imagec, CV_BGR2GRAY); // where image is the example image you shown
cv::GaussianBlur(imagec,imagec, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT ); //blur image
cv::Canny(imagec, imagec, 20, 60, 3);
```

Results for example image 1 you gave:
[image]

As you can see after going through the code, the image became blank(totally black). The image quite big, hence bit difficult to show all in one window.

Results for example 2 you showed me:
[image]

The outline can be seen, but one method to solve this, is to introduce an ROI of about 20 to 30 pixels from the dimension of the image, so for instance, if image dimension is 640x320, the ROI may be 610x 290, where it is placed in the center of the image.

So now, let me introduce you my real method:

> 1) run all the images through the codes above to find edges
>
> 2) check which images doesn't have any any edges( images with no edges
>   will have 0 pixel with values more then 0 or little pixels with values more then 0, so set a slightly higher threshold to play it safe? You adjust accordingly, how many pixels to identify your images )
>
> 3) Save/Name out all the images without edges, which will be the images
>   you are trying to separate out from the rest.
>
> 4) The end.

EDIT(TO ANSWER THE COMMENT, would have commented back, but my reply is too long):

true about the blurring part. To minimise usage of blurring, you can first do an "elimination-like process", so those smooth like images in image 1 will be already separated and categorised into images you looking for.

From there you do a second test for the remaining images, which will be the "blurring".

If you really wish to avoid blurring, what I notice is that your example image 1 can be categorised as "smooth surface" while your example image 2 can be categorised as "rough-like surface", meaning which it be noisy, which led me to introduce the blurring in the first place.

From my experience and if I do remember correctly, such rough-like surfaces is very good in "watershed" or "clustering through colour" method, they blend very well, unlike the smooth images.

Since the leftover images are high chances of rough images, you can try the watershed method, and canny, you will find it be a black image, if I am not wrong. Try a line maybe like this:

`pyrMeanShiftFiltering( image, images, 10, 20, 3)`

I am not very sure if such method will be more expensive than Gaussian blurring. but you can try both and compare the computational speed for both.

In regard to your comment on grayscale images:

> Converting to grayscale sounds risky - loosing color information may
>   trigger lot's of false positives

My answer:

> I don't really think so. If your images you are trying to segment out
>   are of one colour, changing to grayscale doesn't matter. Of course if
>   you snap a photo of a blue sky, it might cause to be a false negative,
>   but as you said, those are ok.
>
> If you think about it, images with people, etc inside, the intensity
>   change differs quite a lot. (of course unless your photograph have
>   extreme cases, like a green ball on a field of grass)
>
> I do admit that converting to grayscale loses information. But in your
>   case, I doubt it will affect much, in fact, working with grayscale
>   images is faster and less expensive.

Comment: Ignoring transparent pixels would make more sense :)
Converting to grayscale sounds risky - loosing color information may trigger lot's of false positives.
Blur is very expensive. 3x3 kernel is small but I think it's useless with large images. For example dust spot from Hi-res cam may have more than 10x10 pixels. Increasing kernel size makes processing more intensive.
Note that images that I've shown have fairly reduced size. The bigger one originally had roughly 10MP and I may encounter images even twice of that size (up to 30MP). I don't even want to think of blurring them ;)

Comment: @SiliconMind, my reply is a little too long, check my answer, the "edit" part for my reply to your comment. Cheers(: Hope I helped a little or give you more options on how you would tackle such problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use entropy based approach. I don't have any custom code to share, but the following blog entry should push you in right direction.

http://envalo.com/image-cropping-php-using-entropy-explained/

The thing is, that the uniform images will have very low entropy compared to those with something interesting in them.

So the question is to find the correct threshold and process the whole set.

Comment: The idea is great unfortunately it looks like very computation-expensive. The author uses so many filters and calculations that I doubt it would make sense in my case. It might work well for small web images but doing all that stuff with 20MP image would melt my CPU :) However +1 for an interesting idea.

Comment: Wow, that's my blog post. Just... wow. Never though nonsense I wrote would appear anywhere. I'm not sure if the entropy method is the best, but it could work. I am not the original author of the entropy code, and by no means an expert, but if you scaled the source image down and maybe even ran a very weak blur over the result before doing the entropy, you would likely be able to determine if the image has anything interesting pretty easily. Still expensive, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would generate a color histogram for each image and compare how much they differ from a given pattern.

Maybe you want to normalize the brightness first to simplify the matching.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then this solution won't work. Because histogram for very "redish" image would be totally different than histogram for very "bluish" one. Even if both images would have the same pattern. For example if you take the first picture that I uploaded and change it's hue significantly, you'll get different histogram because there are different colors used.

Comment: I Think you need to be more specific, what kind of images you want to detect. The Example you gave has very specific color-histograms. Only a few, very similar colors are used in your example images. So me attempt is, detect images which use only very few and similar colors (This can be done by analyzing the histogram).

Comment: Your answer was to compare histograms to the given pattern. The problem is that if I get very similar image to the one that I've uploaded, but in blue colors, then the pattern won't match. The problem is that I can encounter various color. The images might be bluer, greener and so on. There is no rule. So I'd have to have a "proof" histogram for every possible image pattern, color and intensity (larger, brighter, greener, bluer, etc). I think that it's not possible to do this the way you suggest.

Comment: @SiliconMind: But they will all have only a small spectrum of very dominant colors, which can be detected via a histogram. A image containing e.g. a photograph will nearly always have quite a spread spectum, which looks very different.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't fully understand how your solution would work. Could you show an example or write more how this should work?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it:

- Find the average R, G, and B values across the image
- Calculate a value for each pixel that is the sum of the differences of each channel from the average
- Remove the top 0.1% of values to ignore outliers
- Check the largest remaining difference against a threshold (you'll probably need to determine this threshold by trial and error)

Comment: If I understand you correctly then this means that I'd have to use double the amount of memory for each image, just to store the results of calculations, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, although you could only keep the top 0.1% at any given time, and at the end compare the lowest value, rather than removing them as specified in the initial algorithm.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. A buffer for `n * 0.001` pixels to store extreme values looks way better. Simplest solutions are sometimes too simple :) It's almost the same what I was considering in the beginning however now it looks quite promising. Maybe I'll combine this with contrast bumping for better results?

Comment: I see no reason to change the contrast, since it won't improve results at all. Outliers will remain outliers, and everything else will remain everything else.

Comment: If I add contrast bumping I could probably simplify this a bit and use only one pass without calculating averages. Uniform image will either turn black or white. I could count pixels that do not fit this pattern and if I hit some boundaries then I know it is not a uniform image. It's just a theory though.

Comment: 1. Contrast bumping requires its own pass, which will undoubtedly be slower than calculating an average. 2. The only good it can do you is clipping outliers to full black or white. If you add too much contrast, you'll lose information and you won't be able to process the image in any meaningful way.

Comment: I don't have to bump contrast on the whole image in advance. I can do everything in one pass. Apply contrast filter to the pixel then add it's new color to the `counter`. If I my `counter` will start getting more colors in larger amounts then I can immediately stop because this will not be an uniform image. Uniform image with maxed contrast should generally be one color image (at least that is what I think). So if I start getting a deviations from this color in larger amounts, then this is definitely not a uniform image. Does that makes sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47502/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-siliconmind)

Comment: Bad news. I've tried this algorithm and the results are rather poor. Many of my uniform images are not detected. Maybe they aren't that uniform after all, but tuning the algorithm (increasing tolerance) resulted in a lot of false positives. However surprisingly, my initial idea with bumping contrast helped a lot! The results are not perfect yet but increasing contrast by 50% yields far better results.

I would love to test other options but most of them are too CPU heavy :(

Answer (score 0):

The following apprach might be usefull.

1. Derive local binary pattern in 5x5 window centered around every pixel. So for one pixel you have 15 boolean values. In some direction (Clockwise or anticlockwise) calculate the number 1-0 and 0-1 changes. This is the feature value of the center pixel.
2. For all 20x20 window derive the variance of the pixel feature values.
3. If you take variance of the variances , for a uniform image it should approach towards zero. Whereas for other images it would be quite high. In this way there might be no necessary to fix thresholds and local binary pattern takes care of the potential uneven illumination.

Comment: `15 boolean values` - I think you meant 25 :) Anyway, the idea is tempting. The problem is that it means that I'd have to analyse n*25 pixels for each image. For a 10 MP image that's quite big number. I didn't test this but sounds quite time intensive.

Comment: In that case you can get the edges first using the algorithm described in http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Downloads/LBPMatlab or canny edge detection. Then only perform the analysis on the edge pixels. The rest are going to be zero anyway.

Answer (score 0):

for each of the R,G,B channels, calculate the standard deviation of intensity. If it is low enough, you have an uniform image.

If you are worried about having different uniform areas, calculate the standard deviations for, say, each 20x20 square separately, then calculate average of the standard deviations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can solve your problem using machine learning (classification). It is easier than it sounds. I will give an example:

1 - Feature extraction: compute a color histogram from all images (a histogram of RGB values). Probably you will want to reduce the number of possible values of R,G and B, so your histogram does not grows so large (this is known as requantization). For example, you could make a histogram that accepts 4 different values of R, G and B, yielding an histogram with 4*4*4 bins: [(R=1, G=1, B=1), (R=1, G=1, B=2), ... (R=4, G=4, B=4)].

2 - Manually mark some images that know that are not photographs.

3 - Train a classifier: now that you have examples of images that are photographs and images that are not photographs, you can use this information to train a classifier. This classifier, given a histogram can be used to predict the image is photography or not.

If you do not want to spend time on the classifier, you could try a more simple approach:

- Compute the histogram from the image It that you want to know if it is a photography or not;
- Compare the histogram of It with the histograms of all marked images and find the most similar histogram (for example, you can sum the differences between bins);
- If the image with the most similar histogram is a photography, then you classify the image It as a photography. Otherwise, classify It as not being a photography

Comment: I have thousands of images and new are coming every day. So it sounds like this solution would require massive amount of processing time to collect the data and massive amount of memory to store and compare histograms.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my answer. I write a simple demo to explain my idea by C. You can find it in [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexchicn/8979667).

Ready:

- one color/pixel contains three channels *(four channels if you have alpha data)*
- every channel has 8 bit(256) in common

Make some defines:

```
#define IMAGEWIDTH      20 // Assumed
#define IMAGEHEIGHT     20 // Assumed
#define CHANNELBIT      8
#define COLORLEVEL      256

typedef struct tagPixel
{
    unsigned int R : CHANNELBIT;
    unsigned int G : CHANNELBIT;
    unsigned int B : CHANNELBIT;
} Pixel;
```

Collect every count of color for every `COLORLEVEL` in each channel:

```
void TraverseAndCount(Pixel image_data[IMAGEWIDTH][IMAGEHEIGHT]
    , unsigned int red_counts[COLORLEVEL]
    , unsigned int green_counts[COLORLEVEL]
    , unsigned int blue_counts[COLORLEVEL]);
```

Next step is very important. **Analyze the count of color**:

```
// just a very simple way to smooth the curve of the counts of colors
// and you can replace it with another way you want
unsigned int CalculateRange(unsigned int min_count
    , unsigned int blur_size
    , unsigned int color_counts[COLORLEVEL]);
```

This function does:

- i smooth the curve of each channel count in axis - `COLORLEVEL` by `blur_size`. *(you can smooth it by another way)*
- calculate the range of counts that is more than `min_count`

At last, calculate the average of range in each channel:

```
// calculate the average of the range for each channel of color
// the value is bigger if the image is more probably photographs
float AverageRange(unsigned int min_count, unsigned int blur_size
    , unsigned int red_counts[COLORLEVEL]
    , unsigned int green_counts[COLORLEVEL]
    , unsigned int blue_counts[COLORLEVEL]);
```

**Note:**

- the result depends the `min_count`. `min_count` should bigger than 0.
- the bigger result is more probably that the image is a photo.
- for a photograph, bigger result is more probably in smaller `min_count`.